# Почему в [HttpPatch] не получается изменить данные поля?

Tags: .net

Создаю простое CRUD приложение.
На этапе обновления данных пользователя не могу получить обновленные данные.

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> UpdateUser(int id, [FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<User> userData)
        {
            var userToUpdate = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id);

            if (userToUpdate == null) return NotFound();

            if (userData != null)
            {
                userData.ApplyTo(userToUpdate);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Ok(userToUpdate);
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
```

Так например, я хочу изменить почту пользователя и отправляю в userData:

```
[
    {
        "email": "asya@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

Но на сервер приходит:

```
[
    {
        "path": null,
        "op": null
    }
]
```

И я получаю ошибку:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path')
```

В Program.cs у меня добавлен пакет Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Почему на сервер не приходят мои данные с измененной почтой? Как это исправить?

Comment: 1) Почему на вход даете массив Email'ов? 2) (..., [FromBody] User user)

Comment: @LiptonDev, спасибо за отклик. Пока не особо разбираюсь в C#: 1) почему на вход подается массив? Я делаю по этому [туториалу](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-6.0#action-method-code); 2) попробовал исправить на  [FromBody] User user: получилось тоже самое, что и с PUT: требуется замена всех полей, а мне нужно заменить только одно.

Comment: Слишком давно смотрел Patch, не помню от слова совсем уже всего, но думаю, что на тело запроса у вас не правильное